# How to find unnecessary null operators?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullable-reference-types

I'm updating an older solution with millions of LoC to NRT. The process is going through several iterations.

How can I find null forgiving (`!`), null coalescing (`??`), and optional chaining (`?.`) operators that have become obsolete without having to look at *all* of them?

---

Pointless sample code just because SO likes its sample codes:

```
#nullable enable

// Solution/SectionA/SubZ/Project42/Thing.cs
class Thing
{
    // This property had its nullability changed at some point
    // by someone else and you don't know this happened.
    public string/*?*/ Prop { get; set; } = "";
}

// Imagine several hundred files with thousands of lines

// Solution/SectionB/SubY/Project4711/App.cs
class App
{
    public void Method(Thing t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Prop?.Substring(3)); // How do you find this ?. ?
    }
}
```

Simply searching for usages of `Thing.Prop` is not possible, since I would have to know that `Thing.Prop` changed, which I don't.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) though I have no experience to back that claim up. There's a tutorial here: [Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).

Comment: Maybe try to write your own Roslyn analyser, or search whether it s possible to extend existing ones such as stylecop